# Dúvida com WebRequest método get passando token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando ler os dados de um pedido, onde envio as informações via get, 
Erro: Não é possível enviar um conteúdo com este tipo de verbo.

```html
     public string ConsultaPedido(string urlpedido, string NumeroPedido)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpedido + "/" + NumeroPedido +"/");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    AuthToken = "8686330657058660259"
                });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que a API que você quer consultar pede como JSON para a consulta?

Comment: Leonardo, adicionei na imagem, pede o número do pedido e o token

Comment: adicionei na pergunta uma imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Método GET não contém Body**, ou seja você precisa enviar o `AuthToken` no Header como nosso colega disse. Tenta assim:

```
public string ConsultaPedido(string urlpedido, string NumeroPedido)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpedido + "/" + NumeroPedido +"/");
        //request.ContentType = "application/json"; removendo o body
        request.Method = "GET";

        /*using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                AuthToken = "8686330657058660259"
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }Não há necessidade de adicionar um body, ao invés disso adicione no Header.*/

        request.Headers["AuthToken"] = "8686330657058660259";//Adicionando o AuthToken  no Header da requisição

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Retirei a linha de adicionar o Header dessa [pergunta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519788/add-custom-header-in-httpwebrequest)

Comment: Leonardo, deu certo, só que veio o html da página e não os dados, o que poderia ter mudado? agradeço imensamente

Comment: Deu certo, o caminho da api estava errado, ajustei e agora deu certo, vou agora fazer o processo DeserializeObject, agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Mas fora o caminho, você utilizou a solução que eu mandei ? só para eu saber se estava correto mesmo

Comment: Sim, deu certo, você estava certo, uma dúvida, quando está sendo feito
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ele está preenchendo os dados da classe ou ainda não?

Comment: Ele já preenche os dados sim, o ato de deserializar é preencher os dados msm coisa ;)

Comment: Leonardo, a sua ajuda foi fundamental para desenrola as coisas aqui, agora tenho mais um desafio que seria criar uma API que vai receber vários itens, eu sei que é pedir demais, mais independente se você tiver como fazer uma consultoria nas dúvidas, agente combina alguma coisa:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261017/api-que-recebe-um-array-de-itens

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando enviar um Body em um verbo GET, onde não é possível.
O que você pode fazer e é o mais comum é você enviar o token no Header.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Normalmente eu faço assim, um método de exemplo de um teste que eu fiz:

```
private List<UserCoupon> GetUserCoupons()
{
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(APIUrl) };

    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetToken());

        int userId = GetUserId();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.GetAsync($"api/coupon/couponlistbyuser?UserId={userId}").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var ret = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserCoupon>>(ret.Result);
            return list;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```