# Como ler um arquivo JSON usando C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho o meu código que faz uma leitura de uma API externa e me retorna as informações, eu gostaria de ler estas informações ou adicionar elas em uma classe:

Estou usando o Newtonsoft.Json;

Este o Json:

```
   {
       "success": true,
       "errorMessage": null,
        "answer": {
           "token": "8686330657058660259"
              }
     }



        public class usuario
        {
            public string success { get; set; }
            public string errorMessage { get; set; }
            public List<String> answer { get; set; }
        }




        public string ConsultaUsuario(string url)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    username = "sistemacdm",
                    password = "qZrm4Rqk"
                });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                usuario m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<usuario>(json);
                string name = m.success;

                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
```

> Erro:
>
> Uma exceção do tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'
>   ocorreu no Newtonsoft.Json.dll, mas não foi processada no código do
>   usuário
>
> Informações adicionais: Não é possível deserializar o objeto JSON
>   atual (por exemplo, {"name": "value"}) no tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.String]' porque o tipo
>   requer uma matriz JSON (por exemplo, [1 , 2,3]) para deserializar
>   corretamente.
>
> Para corrigir este erro, altere o JSON para uma matriz JSON (por
>   exemplo, [1,2,3]) ou altere o tipo deserializado para que seja um tipo
>   .NET normal (por exemplo, não é um tipo primitivo como inteiro, nem um
>   tipo de coleção como uma matriz ou lista ) que pode ser
>   desserializada a partir de um objeto JSON. JsonObjectAttribute também
>   pode ser adicionado ao tipo para forçá-lo a deserializar a partir de
>   um objeto JSON.
>
> Path 'answer.token', linha 1, posição 54.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para transformar um JSON em classe c# você precisa utilizar o famoso `Deserialize`. Mas antes disso você precisa mapear a sua classe perfeitamente igual ao JSON. Vamos a um exemplo utilizando a biblioteca [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

Digamos que o seu JSON seja esse:

```
}
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
   'Action',
   'Comedy'
  ]
}
```

Você precisa criar uma classe idêntica ao mesmo para poder deserializar:

```
public static class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Datetime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public List<String> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Agora, para converter o seu JSON em Classe C# faça:

```
Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

Exemplo retirado do próprio site da biblioteca.

OBS: Como o Renan respondeu, se você utilizar o [RESTSharp](http://restsharp.org/), além de fazer a requisição ele já deserializa a sua classe. Mas como o foco da pergunta não é fazer a requisição e já deserializar não achei necessário explicar.

EDIT:

A única coisa que esta errado no seu código é a classe que você quer deserializar:

`answer` Não é um `List<String>` e sim um Objeto Answer. Segue correção da classe `usuário`:

```
public class usuario
{
        public string success { get; set; }
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public Answer answer { get; set; }
}
```

Adicione no seu projeto a classe Answer:

```
 public class Answer
 {
        public string token { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Leonardo, sua resposta quase deu certo, eu já estou usando o Newtonsoft.Json; , veja na minha pergunta, a estrutura esta igual ao seu exemplo, mais não deu certo, dar um erro quando vai ler o token

Comment: @itasouza pronto, agora entendi o problema, aplica o EDIT e vê se funciona

Comment: @itasouza se não funcionar volta aqui denovo com o erro que fazemos funcionar ;)

Comment: Leonardo, deu certo, agradeço imensamente a ajuda!

Comment: Por nada, depois que consegue a primeira o céu é o limite ;), eu sofri muito com deserialização kkk ainda sofro as vezes... boa sorte

Comment: Estou fazendo isso pela primeira vez, então estou apanhando, para completar, eu fiz apenas primeira parte que seria pegar o token, 
Agora eu preciso enviar o token junto com o número do pedido fazendo o get, também estou tendo problemas, se você conseguir ajudar em agradeço, o exemplo que postaram não ajudou muito:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260751/d%C3%BAvida-com-webrequest-m%C3%A9todo-get-passando-token

Comment: Cara, fique uns 30 min pesquisando na internet como fazer isto......você explicou de forma clara e objetiva.showwwwwww