# Api com Array de itens não recebe os dados postados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma Api que recebe os dados postados conforme mostrar a imagem, acontece que os dados estão vindo vazio, agradeço a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   //http://localhost:49764/api/unidade/carrinho/consultaUnidadeAtendimento
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("unidade/carrinho/consultaUnidadeAtendimento")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento(ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel consultaAtendimento)
        {

            try
            {
                string numeroCarrinho = consultaAtendimento.NumeroCarrinho.ToString();
                string cep = consultaAtendimento.Cep;
                bool retiraLocal = consultaAtendimento.RetiraNoLocal;

               var tTabela = "";
               var listar = "";
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { usuario = listar.ToArray() });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }

        }



        public class ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel
        {
            [JsonProperty("numeroCarrinho")]
            public long NumeroCarrinho { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("itens")]
            public dynamic Itens { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("cep")]
            public string Cep { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("retiraNoLocal")]
            public bool RetiraNoLocal { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: fiz mesmo post aqui com seu objeto e funcionou normalmente  não mudei nada

Comment: Como e possivel? o que pode ser isso? não faz sentido funciona com você e comigo não, será que tem alguma configuração que não tenho?

Comment: Descobri o erro, postman configurado para text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta enviar o objeto JSON altera no postman [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

assim você trabalha com objeto fica mais simples

```
 public class Model
    {
        [JsonProperty("numeroCarrinho")]
        public long NumeroCarrinho { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("itens")]
        public List<Carrinho> Itens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cep")]
        public string Cep { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("retiraNoLocal")]
        public bool RetiraNoLocal { get; set; }
    }

    public class Carrinho
    {
        [JsonProperty("codigo")]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("qtd")]
        public int Qtd { get; set; }
    }
```

json enviado

```
 {
        "numeroCarrinho":122865,
        "itens":[
            {"codigo":"PA00058","qtd":1},
            {"codigo":"MA00068","qtd":1},
            {"codigo":"PA00004","qtd":1}
        ],
        "cep":"41706670",
        "retiradaNoLocal":false
    }
```

Comment: Agradeço imensamente! agora vem a parte mais complicado, veja que estou recebendo um dado dinâmico, os itens, como eu posso pegar eles, agora e o problema, se puder ajudar agradeço

Comment: precisa saber cada um não melhor como é um campo tratar tudo como lista de string e no banco salvar em uma tabela itens do carrinho exemplo

Comment: O problema e que vem o código do produto que seria o PA00058 e a quantidade na frente

Comment: da uma olhada ai testei aqui funcionou certinho vê se isso atende seu cenário

Comment: vai precisar mudar o Json neste caso

Comment: clica em aceitar minha resposta ai se foi util

Comment: Pronto! valeu !

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode receber o `Objeto C#` no parâmetro da requisição, você recebe o JSON(string) e depois [deserializa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260829/como-ler-um-arquivo-json-usando-c/260847#260847) o mesmo.

Comment: Pode me dar uma ajuda? pode me ajuda mais uma vez me mostrando o caminho a seguir? agradeço

Comment: ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel>(consultaAtendimento.ToString()); seria isso? vou testar

Comment: Troca `ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel` por `String` no método `ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento`

Comment: E a pessoa que vai te enviar ela precisa enviar um JSON valido em relação ao seu objeto (como eu ja tinha explicado na outra pergunta)

Comment: Leonardo, sem querer abusar mais poderia postar um exemplo, seria bom para ficar registrado, acredito que outras pessoas teria o mesmo problema um dia

Comment: Descobri o erro, postman configurado para text