# Api que recebe um Array de itens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso fazer a criação de uma API que vai receber o conteúdo a baixo:

```
{
  "numeroCarrinho": 122865,
  "itens": {
    "PA00058": 1,
    "MA00068": 1,
    "PA00004": 1
  },
  "cep": "41706670",
  "retiraNoLocal": false
}
```

Exemplo:
localhost:7630/api/unidade/consulta/carrinho/122865/PA00058:1,MA00068:1,PA00004:1/41706670/false

O problema e que os itens seria dinâmico, um array de itens, como eu poderia fazer isso, fiz um exemplo mais gostaria de saber como posso pegar todos os itens separados.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("unidade/consulta/carrinho/{numerocarrinho}/{itens}/{cep}/{retiralocal}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento(string numerocarrinho, string[] itens, string cep, string retiralocal)
{

    try
    {
       var tTabela = "";
       var listar = "";
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { usuario = listar.ToArray() });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

```
public JObject PostSavePage(dynamic testObject)
{
    return testObject;
}
```

ficaria assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Update:

Controller completo de Exemplo:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/values")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("postsave")]
        public JObject PostSavePage(dynamic testObject)
        {
            return testObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agradeço Thiago, você poderia postar o seu código de exemplo? agradeço a ajuda

Comment: @itasouza feito.. aí dentro da chamada lá voce manipula o objeto , abs!

Comment: Thiago, agradeço imensamente sua resposta, eu fiz o exemplo, o detalhe e que os dados postados não estão vindo, eu abri uma nova dúvida, se você conseguir ajudar eu agradeço:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261193/api-com-array-de-itens-n%C3%A3o-recebe-os-dados-postados

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar uma classe que represente os dados a serem recebidos pelo método, assim seu código fica mais legível. Os dados seriam enviados no body da requisição.

Classe:

```
public class ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("cep")]
        public string Cep { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("itens")]
        public dynamic Itens { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("numeroCarrinho")]
        public long NumeroCarrinho { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("retiraNoLocal")]
        public bool RetiraNoLocal { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [Route("unidade/consultaUnidadeAtendimento")]
public HttpResponseMessage ConsultaUnidadeAtendimento(ConsultaUnidadeAtendimentoModel consultaAtendimento)
{

    try
    {
       var tTabela = "";
       var listar = "";
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { usuario = listar.ToArray() });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tomaz, agradeço imensamente sua resposta, eu fiz o exemplo, o detalhe e que os dados postados não estão vindo, eu abri uma nova dúvida, se você conseguir ajudar eu agradeço:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261193/api-com-array-de-itens-n%C3%A3o-recebe-os-dados-postados